# Approaches to distinguish bare soil from artificial soil in an urban context with Pleiades imagery?

Tags: qgis, r, remote-sensing, multi-band, soil

My colleagues and I are trying to improve an existing landcover map by improving the distinction between *bare soils* and *artificial soils* (e.g. concrete, asphalt). We need a good detection of bare soils because we're studying wild bee species that live in the ground.
To do that, we only have a Pleiades image (with a spatial resolution of roughly 1m for visible bands, and probably less for the NIR) and... mostly QGIS (or R or ArcGIS). Our study landscape is composed of urban and suburban areas, with mainly **calcareous or marly soils** (if relevant, we're studying the city of Dijon, in France).

The problem is that we're not very experienced in urban remote sensing. I have read [Differentiating bare soil and urban areas in Landsat 4-5 land cover classification](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177159), but as almost all answers suggest using spectral indices involving MIR or SWIR (bands we do not have), I was wondering whether someone could suggest an approach that would give good results with Pleiades imagery or similar (i.e. **RGB+NIR bands only**)?

Comment: https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/1/94/htm, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271702357_Land_Cover_Classification_in_a_Complex_Urban-Rural_Landscape_with_QuickBird_Imagery

Comment: @Matt, thank you for your comment. However, unless I'm mistaken, these papers use spectral bands we do not have.

Comment: The first article uses Landsat, which is much coarser than the data you have, and focused on sub-pixel analysis and fractional cover. The second article uses Quickbird, which has roughly the same bands and resolution as Pleiades, so should be comparable.